# Given a discriminant, get type of a property for corresponding member of discriminated union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, discriminated-union, mapped-types

I have the following discriminated union, where the property `id` acquires a different type based on the value of the discriminant:

```
type TableKind = 'administration' | 'data'

type AdministrationTableId = 'Modules' | 'Users' | 'Roles'
type DataTableId = number

type GenericIdentifier<K extends TableKind, ID> = { kind: K, id: ID }

type AdministrationTableIdentifier = GenericIdentifier<'administration', AdministrationTableId>
type DataTableIdentifier = GenericIdentifier<'data', DataTableId>

type TableIdentifier = AdministrationTableIdentifier | DataTableIdentifier
```

I would like to make a generic type that takes the discriminant and returns the type of `id` property of the corresponding union member:

```
type GetTableIdType<K extends TableKind> = ???

type AdminId = GetTableIdType<'administration'> // returns AdministrationTableID
type DataId = GetTableIdType<'data'> // returns DataTableId
```

Is this possible? How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)

```js
type TableKind = 'administration' | 'data'

type AdministrationTableId = 'Modules' | 'Users' | 'Roles'
type DataTableId = number

type GenericIdentifier<K extends TableKind, ID> = { kind: K, id: ID }

type AdministrationTableIdentifier = GenericIdentifier<'administration', AdministrationTableId>

type DataTableIdentifier = GenericIdentifier<'data', DataTableId>

type TableIdentifier = AdministrationTableIdentifier | DataTableIdentifier


type GetTableIdType<K extends TableKind> = Extract<TableIdentifier, { kind: K }>['id']

type AdminId = GetTableIdType<'administration'> // returns AdministrationTableID
type DataId = GetTableIdType<'data'> // returns DataTableId
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQNIEsB2ATKBeKAcjmwFst0BnYAJzmHQHtNCoAfI7euQgKF9CQoAQTIVqdBs3jIIASVwFCAWUbYArikqsOhAKqUINbeyIAlRlr6DoAEW4yUC-FEzrSCI-xtQA4hEwjdABjBQCGADN0IwAeVCgIAA9gAOxKWEQUDBwAGig5WwA+FwBvKABrLGwALihUPPQa-NsoAF9vcGhRckwqWnomTEd5bHD0KKMXf0CaELDMSOiaGOIxXokB5kI87vF+qSHMkcKOoXtgOGH5xcmCaaDQ0YXxpZWuC+2oc8ujhROBToZWTXF63ERrPqSQZXJ43Gimb4wsYTGj8AFCfzAGEwTpxBLJVLpYbZbDFAgAUWSdGCwBiSOeKLyZUqOFq8VahQA2oRGoQALqnLprZx3CBY37YHGQFYkHqQzYsYoAeiVUBoYvUNEw6V26320N+tnRdm4Ir8YuxuMI7x4ytV6uAmu1XwcEqAA)

Comment: Awesome, your approach works like a charm, thanks! But your example is technically incorrect, the generic now return the union memeber, not id type. You can fix this by adding `["id"]` at the end of the generic. Do this in your post and playground and I will acccept your answer!